# IOS: animation deceleration for a button

Tags: ios, animation

In my app I move a button with this code:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"timerView" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    [timerView setCenter:CGPointMake(967, 80)];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

but I want that the animation decelerate first to arrive to the point, how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Add this line,

```
 [UIView setAnimationCurve: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
```